# Percent Relative Layout with Android Nougat

Tags: android

I used percent relative layout in my project. It working good under android 7. 
But I tested with nougat. Its not working.

Waiting Your Helps.

Answer (score 1):

As documentation says, after Oreo(maybe you are using the 26 SDK?) it's deprecated, you will need to use ConstraintLayout

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Hope this helps